# Группировка и подсчет по дате MySQL

Tags: mysql, дата, sql

В базе дата записана в формате datetime, можно ли сделать подсчет по Date, без Time?
Сделать группировку по Date

> 2014-05-08 16:00:00

Подсчитать количество записей за 2014-05-08, отбросив 16:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT
    D
    ,COUNT(*) C
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CAST(DateTimeField AS DATE) D
    FROM
        TableName
) X
GROUP BY
    D
```

Comment: мало вложенных запросов.

Answer (score 1):

В mysql есть функция DATE(), которая в качестве аргумента принимает DATETIME и возвращает date часть